# Measuring time using pycuda.driver.Event gives wrong results

Tags: python, time, pycuda

I ran [SimpleSpeedTest.py](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/SimpleSpeedTest) from the PyCuda examples, producing the following output:

```
Using nbr_values == 8192
Calculating 100000 iterations
SourceModule time and first three results:
0.058294s, [ 0.005477  0.005477  0.005477]
Elementwise time and first three results:
0.102527s, [ 0.005477  0.005477  0.005477]
Elementwise Python looping time and first three results:
2.398071s, [ 0.005477  0.005477  0.005477]
GPUArray time and first three results:
8.207257s, [ 0.005477  0.005477  0.005477]
CPU time measured using :
0.000002s, [ 0.005477  0.005477  0.005477]
```

**The first four time measurements are reasonable, the last one (0.000002s) however is way off**. The CPU result should be the slowest one but it is orders of magnitude faster than the fastest GPU method. So obviously the measured time must be wrong. This is strange since the same timing method seems to work fine for the first four results.

So I took some code from SimpleSpeedTest.py and made a small **test file** [2], which produced:

```
time measured using option 1:
0.000002s 
time measured using option 2:
5.989620s
```

**Option 1** measures the duration using `pycuda.driver.Event.record()` (as in SimpleSpeedTest.py), **option 2** uses `time.clock()`. Again, option 1 is off while option 2 gives a reasonable result (the time it takes to run the test file is around 6s).

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Since using option 1 is endorsed in SimpleSpeedTest.py, could it be my setup that is causing the problem? I am running a GTX 470, Display Driver 301.42, CUDA 4.2, Python 2.7 64, PyCuda 2012.1, X5650 Xeon

[2] **Test file:**

```
import numpy
import time
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit

n_iter = 100000
nbr_values = 8192 # = 64 * 128 (values as used in SimpleSpeedTest.py)

start = drv.Event() # option 1 uses pycuda.driver.Event
end = drv.Event()

a = numpy.ones(nbr_values).astype(numpy.float32) # test data

start.record() # start option 1 (inserting recording points into GPU stream)
tic = time.clock() # start option 2 (using CPU time)

for i in range(n_iter):
    a = numpy.sin(a) # do some work

end.record() # end option 1
toc = time.clock() # end option 2

end.synchronize() 

events_secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
time_secs = toc - tic 

print "time measured using option 1:"
print "%fs " % events_secs
print "time measured using option 2:"
print "%fs " % time_secs
```

Comment: You're not running anything on the GPU (`testfile2.py`), then only thing you do is creating a numpy array. So I guess `drv.Event` measures the spent time on the GPU, not the CPU.

Comment: @dav1d Yes, this could well be the problem. But if this is the case, why does 'SimpleSpeedTest.py' use option 1 for measuring the time a calculation on the CPU takes?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe it's a bug. Since it's a wiki, you can edit the file and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for emailing me. I'm sure that worked when I posted the code (2 years ago?). It was discussed in the forum so I'm pretty sure it wasn't a trivial mistake (well, I hope so). Maybe pycuda handles timing differently now? I was using an earlier CUDA (maybe 2? I remember upgrading to CUDA3 later) and pycuda would have been 2 years younger (I had to submit fixes to support complex nbrs for example). I'd be very happy if you fixed it and submitted a working version back, perhaps including an example output in the comments (to help future debug sessions). Ian.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I contacted [Andreas Klöckner](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda) and he suggested to synchronize on the start event, too.

```
...
start.record()
start.synchronize()
...
```

And this seems to solve the issue!

```
time measured using option 1:
5.944461s
time measured using option 2:
5.944314s
```

Apparently CUDA's behaviour changed in the last two years. I updated [SimpleSpeedTest.py](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/SimpleSpeedTest).

Comment: Adding start.synchronize() waits for the start.record() operation to be pushed to the GPU and the GPU to write a timestamp to memory. The code does not appear to push any additional work to the GPU. It then pushed another CUDA event using stop.record() and calls stop.synchronize() to wait for the GPU to write a timestamp. This is a very inelegant way to capture CPU, not GPU execution time. If you want to capture wall clock time with a high precision monotonic timer I recommend looking at the x86 timestamp counter. This is used by gettimeofday() and QueryPerformanceCounter (>=Win7).